# Max Heap Implementation in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tree, heap

I decided to challenge myself to code this data structure by just seeing how it looks visually and this is what I got. I can change this easily to minheap by changing some greater than (>) operators. If there are ways to make this efficient/more compact, I'd love to hear it.

```py
class MaxHeap:
    def __init__(self, List=None):
        """
        Initialises the data structure

        if a List is added as an argument, then it will make add the values in the list to the heap
        """
        self.array = []
        self.length = 0
        if List:
            for value in List:
                self.insert(value)

    def __str__(self):
        """
        for showing the heap on print()
        """
        return str(self.array)

    def get_max(self):
        return self.array[0] if self.length else None


    def compare_to_parent(self, index):
        """
        recursive function

        - used in insertion
        - index refers to the the new node that was just inserted
        - checks if the value added is in the right place in the heap, by comparing it with its parents
            + if the value of the new node is greater, than the places of the parent and the new value will be switched,
                and checking will be performed on the new position of the new value and its new parent node, until the parent
                node is greater than the new value.
            + if the value of the parent node is already greater than the checking stops.
            + if the 0th index is reached, then the check is complete.
        """
        if index == 0:
            return True
        elif index == 1:
            parent_index = 0
        else:
            parent_index = index//2

        if self.array[parent_index] > self.array[index]:
            return True
        else:
            self.array[parent_index], self.array[index] = self.array[index], self.array[parent_index]
            self.compare_to_parent(parent_index)

    def compare_to_child(self, parent_index, left_index, right_index, largest_index):
        """
        Iterative function, because if recursion is performed, it may exceed its limit

        - used in popping/removing the max value
        - parent index refers to the most recently added value to the list which replaces the max and becomes the root node instead
        - largest_index refers to the largest index in the list, for which the checking will stop if reached.
        - checks if the new value of node is in the right place, by comparing with its children
            + if there is a child greater than the new value, the greater child will switch it's position with it, and
                it keeps happening till the left index or the right index, becomes larger than the largest possible index in the list
            + if neither child is greater, then the checking stops.
        """
        while True:

            if left_index > largest_index:
                break

            elif right_index > largest_index:
                if self.array[left_index] > self.array[parent_index]:
                    self.array[parent_index], self.array[left_index] = self.array[left_index], self.array[parent_index]
                break

            else:
                if self.array[left_index] > self.array[parent_index] and self.array[left_index] > self.array[right_index]:
                    self.array[parent_index], self.array[left_index] = self.array[left_index], self.array[parent_index]
                    parent_index = left_index
                elif self.array[right_index] > self.array[parent_index] and self.array[right_index] > self.array[left_index]:
                    self.array[parent_index], self.array[right_index] = self.array[right_index], self.array[parent_index]
                    parent_index = right_index
                else:
                    break    

            left_index = parent_index*2 + 1
            right_index = parent_index*2 + 2    

    def insert(self, value):
        """
        inserts a value to the heap

        - no checking occurs until there is atleast 2 values, since there is no point in checking the parent node, 
         when the only value is in the root node.
        """
        self.array.append(value)
        if self.length != 0:
            self.compare_to_parent(self.length)
        self.length += 1

    def pop_max(self):
        """
        pops the max out of the heap, which is the first value in the array.
        """
        if self.length == 0:
            return
        elif self.length == 1:
            return self.array.pop()
        else:
            max_value = self.get_max()
            self.array[0] = self.array.pop()
            self.length -= 1
            self.compare_to_child(0, 1, 2, self.length-1)
        return max_value
```